# How do you save your game in Pokemon Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I don't know how to save my game. Does the game save by itself or do you have to do it? If you have to do it, how?

Comment: I was watching a streamer play this game last night and he was saving his game in the menus. I don't own the game though so I cannot tell you where in the menus.

Comment: Usually the game doesn't save by itself, it only does it when connecting to the Internet. In the menu you should have the classic save option like the previous titles. In ORAS the save button was in the DexNav, the fifth icon in the lower part of screen.

Comment: Step 1: Press "X" to open the X-Menu. Step 2: Figure the rest out yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Open the menu with X, then choose the "Save" option.

Answer (score 0):

Open the menu by pressing the X button. 
Tap 'Save'.

The game only automatically saves once, and that is after the main storyline is completed and the credits roll. Any other time you must save manually.